# Is there a common launcher for DosBox and ScummVM games?

Tags: menu, games, emulation

ScummVM comes with a launcher for starting games. After a game is installed, it displays the names in a window that can be run at full-screen and that can be controlled by the keyboard. Other games requiring DosBox, however, cannot be launched from this. Is there a common interface that can be setup to display and launch both ScummVM and DosBox games?

Answer (score 1):

There are too many to list here but the DosBox project wiki maintains a list of frontends.

- [DOSBoxFrontends](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/DOSBoxFrontends)

There's even a handy comparison of features for some of the more popular options.

- [Frontend Comparison](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Frontend_Comparison)

Several of these frontends can handle DosBox + other emulators such as ScummVM. In particular if you're running from Linux you'll probably want to go with [DBGL: DOSBox Game Launcher](http://members.quicknet.nl/blankendaalr/dbgl/). It's written in Java so can run on multiple OSes. You can download it from here:

- [DBGL Download Page](http://members.quicknet.nl/blankendaalr/dbgl/#download)

**sample screenshot**

[image: ss]

One caveat with DBGL, I do not believe it can handle ScummVM games too, it appears to be strictly a DosBox launcher only. I may be wrong on this point but in a cursory glance I couldn't find any way of getting it to do this.